# XAMPP - MySQL not working - alongwith MariaDB on same machine

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, mariadb

I have installed MariaDB and it was working fine. Now I have installed XAMPP and try to run MySQL but it was showing error for not available port number 3306. Then I have manually changed the port number to 3307 in file:

```
D:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
```

But still it is not connecting, now it showing following error message:

```
Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\bin\mysqld.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\data\my.ini" "MySQL"
Expected Path: d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=d:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

I have two questions:

1. First, is it even possible to work with both MySQL and MariaDB on
   same machine?
2. Second, I also tried to stop mysqlq process(running
   for MariaDB), but still getting same error message. It seems that
   even after stopping MariaDB I still unable to run MySQL with XAMPP.

Comment: Yes.  But they must be totally separate -- different trees, different my.cnf, different port.  Or use some kind of VM or Docker.  "With XAMPP" complicates the question.

Comment: Actually, XAMPP will only use MySQL, MariaDB is used by another application.

Comment: @M_Idrees Did you find a solution to run MariaDB and XAMPP with MySQL on the same machine?

Comment: @Rüdiger, No I did not find any solution. I continued work by uninstalling MariaDB.